# How to turn my android to a wacom tablet?

Tags: wacom

I want to try drawing digital but I don't think I'm ready for something like wacom tablet and it's kinda expensive so I don't want to waste my money for something I can't use well. I have a samsung galaxy tab and when I search for a way to avoid buying it, I found that I can turn my tablet to something like it but when I try to download the programs that they recommend in the playstore it said that I have to root my tablet but I don't want to root it.

I was wondering if it is possible to use a tablet (i.e. my samsung galaxy tab) as a Wacom-esque drawing tablet when connected to a hp laptop (without rooting my tablet)?

Answer (score 1):

There’s “GfxTablet“, an Android application that…

> makes it possible to use your device (especially tablets) like a graphics tablet, sending touch data (including pressure!) to any compatible (e.g. GNU/Linux) computer. Requires running the uinput driver on your PC (see website for details).

Resources:

- [F-Droid page](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=at.bitfire.gfxtablet)
- [repository on GitHub](https://github.com/rfc2822/GfxTablet)
- [website](https://rfc2822.github.io/GfxTablet/)

Comment: GfxTablet is no longer maintained.  It seems there are very few tools for doing this...